# How to exclude AdSense Auto Ads on Homepage

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I just want to share what I can do after searching many times about this. This is for self notes but I know many people looking for this. So this code is using Conditional Tags and no need plugin to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this code in inside header, and of course adjust with your own settings.

```
<?php if ( is_single() || is_category() ) : ?>
** place your auto ads code here**
<?php endif ?>
```